# Why can't overriding methods specify a type parameter if the overriden method doesn't?

Tags: java, generics, erasure

The following code does not compile, however, if I change f(object) to f(String) or f(Integer) it compiles.
I've read the other posts about the subject, but I still don't get it, how come the compiler doesn't know which method to use 
(in case of a new instance A a = new B();)

```
public class SampleTester { 
    public static class A {
        public void f(int x) { System.out.print("1"); } 
        public void f(Object x) { System.out.print("2"); } 
    } 
    public static class B extends A { 
           public <T> void f(T x) { System.out.print("3"); } //compiler error
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         A a = new A();
         B b= new B(); 
         a.f(3);
         a.f("foo"); 
         b.f(3);
         b.f("foo"); 
    } 
}
```

If I change `T x` to `Object t` it still doesn't compile, so what's the difference? and besides, why it doesn't just override the function from A? (both has the same signature after type erasure

Comment: I am not sure why this question was downvoted. It seems to be a pretty good question IMO.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, an obvious question would be "So what's the error message?" *Any* question saying that something doesn't compile (or compiles, but throws an exception) should include the error details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `B` extends `A` and thus inherits all the methods that are present in `A`. This means that `B` will have 3 methods :

```
public void f(int x)
public void f(Object x)
public <T> void f(T x)
```

The problem is that `f(T x)` will go through type erasure during compilation and `T` will be replaced with `Object`, thus resulting in a duplicate method since you already have a method that takes an `Object` argument.

To fix this, either remove the method that takes an `Object` argument or provide an upper bound for `T`. (example `T extends Number` so that `T` is replaced with `Number` during type-erasure)

---

To address your comment (which I have now added to your question) :

`public <T> void f(Object x)` doesn't compile because it is not a valid override for `public void f(Object x)` from `A`.

The method `public <T> void f(Object x)` belongs to the subclass and can be called using a superlcass reference as `a.<Integer>f(null);` or `a.<String>f(null);`. Since overriden methods are resolved at runtime **BUT** generics go through type erasure at compile time itself, there is no way for the compiler to know whether to substitute `T` with `Integer` or `String` at compile time.

It is still legal to reverse the methods such that you have the method `public <T> void f(Object x)` in `A` and the method `public void f(Object x)` in `B` since the compiler has all the information necessary to decide what `<T>` should be replaced with.

Comment: But if I change T x to Object t it compiles, so what's the difference?
and besides, why it doesn't just override the function from A? (both has the same signature after type erasure

Comment: It doesn't compile here. Unless you also remove <T> from the method signature. In that case, you simply override the base method.

Comment: @DsCpp My previous explanation was incomplete as it assumed some deeper understanding at your level. Please see the edit for a more clear explanation.

Comment: See the JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1